# Find last element of a list that fits a critera

Tags: python, list, select, element

I have matrix (type list of lists) and I want to select only the last row that fits my critera. Specificly I have this matrix:

```
matrix = [
         [[0], whatever0],
         [[1], whatever1],
         [[1, 0], whatever10],
         [[1, 1], whatever11],
         [[1, 2], whatever12],
         [[1, 3], whatever13],
         [[1, 4], whatever14],
         ]
```

and I want to select only the LAST row i such that len(matrix[i][0]) == 1, so the answer should return [[1], whatever1].

Haven't found how to answer that specific question yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
matrix = [
    [[0], 'whatever0'],
    [[1], 'whatever1'],
    [[1, 0], 'whatever10'],
    [[1, 1], 'whatever11'],
    [[1, 2], 'whatever12'],
    [[1, 3], 'whatever13'],
    [[1, 4], 'whatever14'],
]

result = next((e for e in reversed(matrix) if len(e[0]) == 1), None)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1], 'whatever1']
```

**Explanation**

First iterate over the list backwards using [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) and return only the elements that have `len(e[0]) == 1`. Then with [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) get only the first result.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It would be most efficient to simply iterate backwards:

```
for i in range(len(matrix), -1, -1):
    if len(matrix[i][0]) == 1:
        print(matrix[i])
        break
else:
    print('No matching row found')
```

Comment: If you don't need the index you should just use [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed).

Comment: `reversed` adds overhead by requiring the creation of a new list first.

Comment: Thanks I stand corrected then. Was under the impression that it's equivalent to `[::-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter)

```
>>> matrix = [
...          [[0], "whatever0"],
...          [[1], "whatever1"],
...          [[1, 1], "whatever11"],
...          [[1, 2], "whatever12"],
...          [[1, 3], "whatever13"],
...          [[1, 4], "whatever14"]
...          ]

res=list(filter(lambda x: x[0][0]>0, matrix))[-1]
```

there res contains last element of first of first item of each matrix item (bolded ones)

...          [[0], "whatever0"],

...          [[**1**], "whatever1"],

...          [[**1**, 1], "whatever11"]

...          [[**1**, 2]**, "whatever12"],

...          [[**1**, 3]**, "whatever13"],

...          [[**1**, 4]**, "whatever14"]